# Java Reverse a linked list pairwise

Tags: java

I am trying to reverse a linked list pairwise i.e as follows

```
1->2->3->4->5 changed to 2->1->4->3->5
```

I have been able to do that recursively. However, I am getting confused while doing it iteratively.

```
public class FastList<Item>
{
    private Node<Item> first;

    private static class Node<Item>
    {
        Item item;  
        Node<Item> next;
    }

    public void swapPairwiseIterative()  // not working
    {
        if(first == null || first.next==null)
            return;

        Node one = first, two;
        first= first.next;

        while ( one != null || one.next != null )
        {
            two = one.next;
            one.next = two.next;
            two.next = one;
            one = one.next.next;
        }
    }
}
```

On debugging, I noticed that I am able to swap the two nodes correctly, but am not able to assign it back to the `first` instance variable, which points to the first element of the list. How do I do that ?

Also, the line

```
first= first.next;
```

looks a bit hacky. Please suggest a more natural way of doing it.

Comment: since I hate to answer people's homeworks with code. just store the pairs. and have a link to the parent for speed. Otherwise every iteration is an average of n/2 acceses.

Comment: Say I am processing the pair `3->4`, how do I change `2` to point to 4 and not 3 given it is a singly linked list.

Comment: Shouldn't `one = one.next.next` be `one = one.next`? since you are swaping one and two, one takes the position of two thus making the start of the next pair be the first node after one, not second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void swapPairwiseIteratively() {
  if(first == null || first.next==null) return;
  Node one = first, two = first.next, prev = null;
  first = two;
  while (one != null && two != null) {
    // the previous node should point to two
    if (prev != null) prev.next = two;
    // node one should point to the one after two
    one.next = two.next;
    // node two should point to one
    two.next = one;
    // getting ready for next iteration
    // one (now the last node) is the prev node
    prev = one;
    // one is prev's successor
    one = prev.next;
    // two is prev's successor's successor
    if (prev.next != null) two = prev.next.next;
    else two = null;
  }
}
```

I am not sure you can do it with only two pointers instead of three. I would work from the solution above (I haven't tested it but it should be correct) and figure out if it can be improved. I don't think the line `first = two` can be removed.

You could remove the condition `if (prev != null)` if you move the first pair swapping out of the loop (an optimization that is premature in this example).

Comment: @OneMoreError if it helped, at least accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either recursively or non-recursively.

```
public void reverseRecursive(Node startNode)
{
    Item tmp;
    if(startNode==null || startNode.next ==null)
        return;
    else
    {

        tmp =  startNode.item;
        startNode.item = startNode.next.item;
        startNode.next.item = tmp;

        reverseRecursive(startNode.next.next);
    }

}
```

Non Recursively

```
public void reverseNonRecursive()
{
    Node startNode = head;
    Item temp;

    while(startNode != null && startNode.next != null)
    {
        temp =  startNode.item;
        startNode.item = startNode.next.item;
        startNode.next.item= temp;
        startNode = startNode.next.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: His code is swapping pointers.  I don't think swapping intrinsic data is what he wants.